# Problems with saving values to array using FileReader

Tags: angular, image, typescript, filereader

I'm working on Angular4 project. I get Blob returned from my API call, then I convert it to base64 but can't manage to save it to the array of pictures (so I can show it with `*ngFor` later).

Here is my API call:

`getImg(): Observable<Blob> {
        const path = *can't show this part*;
        return this.http.get(path, { responseType: "blob" });
}`

And here is what I tried so far:

This function has error at line `this.images[i] = reader.result;`, because it says `Property 'images' does not exist on type 'FileReader'`

```
images: Array<any> = [];

getImages(): void {
for (var i = 0; i < this.myData.length; i++) {
  this.myApiCalls.getImg()
    .subscribe(res => {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(res);
      reader.addEventListener("loadend", function () {
        this.images[i] = reader.result;
      });       
    },
      err => {
        console.log(err.message)
      });
  }
}
```

The other thing I tried is with callbacks, but I still got error, on the same column but for different thing. It says `'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.`

```
getImages(): void {
for (var i = 0; i < this.myData.length; i++) {
  this.myApiCalls.getImg()
    .subscribe(res => {
      this.readImageFile(res, function(e: any) {
        this.fields[i] = e.target.result;
      });       
    },
      err => {
        console.log(err.message)
      });
  }
}

readImageFile(response: Blob, callback: any): void {
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.readAsDataURL(response);
   reader.onloadend = callback 
}
```

So I get data returned back correctly, but the problem is I can't manage to save it to the array. If you guys are able to help me solve that problem I would be very happy.
Thank you.

Comment: hey, @HC1122 Did you tried what iam said as comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you converting it to a base64? You can create a url from the blob with `const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob)` (just remember to revoke the url to free mem after it's not used with `URL.revokeObjectURL(blobUrl)`)? I ask because it's more efficient.

But your code is failing because of a context issue (`this` is not what you expect). The context inside the callback is the reader object. There's a clue in the error `Property 'images' does not exist on type 'FileReader'` - it's showing that `this` is an instance of `FileReader`.

Edit: You should also use `let` on your loop `i`, otherwise `i` won't be what you expect inside the callback.

If you want to preserve the outer scope context then use an arrow function:

```
getImages(): void {
for (let i = 0; i < this.myData.length; i++) {
  this.myApiCalls.getImg()
    .subscribe(res => {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
        this.images[i] = reader.result;
      });
      reader.readAsDataURL(res);
    },
      err => {
        console.log(err.message)
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that I made another edit about using `let` @HC1122

Comment: I recommend you console log `this` in and out of the 'load' callback and make sure it's what you expect and that it has an images array

Answer (score 1):

Here is updated your code please try this once.

```
images: any[]= [];

getImages(): void {
for (var i = 0; i < this.myData.length; i++) {
  this.myApiCalls.getImg()
    .subscribe(res => {
      this.readImageFile(i,res);
    },
      err => {
        console.log(err.message)
      });
  }
//here iam logged console. See values saved array or not.
console.log("Print your Value here once",this.images);
}

readImageFile(indexVal:number,response: Blob): void {
      let self = this;
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(response);
      reader.onloadend = function () {
          self.images[indexVal] = reader.result;
        }
}
```

Try this once and let me know.
I hope its useful to solve your problem.
I all ready worked related this function

Thanks,

Muthukumar

Comment: Hm, currently I got error `self.images[indexVal]` is undefined in console.log

Comment: did you print same like this console.log("Print your Value here once",this.images);?

Comment: reader.onloadend = function () {
//please here first log your output has been got or not once pls.
console.log("Reader Value",reader.result);
          self.images[indexVal] = reader.result;
        }

Comment: Karnan thank you for your help. The problem was like commented below in using `var i` instead of `let i` and because of that Indexes were not as expected.

Comment: ok change like that and try one more time you got as your output has been expected

Comment: please accept my answer if it is solve your problem.

Comment: Yes your code it is also working with using `let`, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer, it may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/16245768/8350917